# How to "overload" functions in Python including objects OR/AND numbers

Tags: python, function, object, overloading

I want to call the function with this two different ways, sharing as parameters strings, numbers and an object with all its possible variable members.

```
class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

position = Coord(100, 150)

def fu (string, nu1, nu2):
    print(string, nu1, nu2)

def fu (string, po):
    print(string, po.x, po.y)


fu("function called with numbers", 10, 20)
fu("function called with class-object", position)
```

> TypeError: fu() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Python *does not support method overloading*.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to call the function `fu` with *three* arguments? Your signatures are either 1 or 2 arguments... also not, you aren't calling it with a "class-object". You mean *an instance of a class*. `position` is an instance of the class object `Coord`

Comment: yes, i already edited, thanks.